# How many integer solutions with negative numbers?

Tags: combinatorics

If a question asked: How many integer solutions of $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=30$ with $-9 \leq x_i \leq 21$? How would this be solved?

I understand how to solve if the inequality was $0 \leq x_i \leq 21$?, but how to solve between a negative and positive inequality?

$N = \binom{30 + 4-1}{30}$

$N(A_i) = \binom{(30 - ?) +4-1}{30 - ?}$

...

Comment: It is the coefficient of $x^{30}$ in $$\frac{x^{-36}(1-x^{30})^4}{(1-x)^4}$$

Comment: @MattSamuel Could you explain this? We have to use sets (finished generating functions chapter).

Comment: The formula for $N$ you give is the unrestricted value.  That is, it would be the answer if the question was how many solutions are there to $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=30$ with $x_i≥0$.  More work is needed to handle a cap, as in $0≤x_i≤21$.

Comment: "set theory" has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: @JeanMarie Ah, sorry, I assumed so because that's our current chapter.

Comment: @MattSamuel $\left[x^{30}\right] \frac{x^{-36}\left(1 - x^{31}\right)^4}{\left(1 - x\right)^4}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $y_i=x_i+9$. Then
$$
y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4=66\\
0\leq y_i\leq 30
$$
Now find the number of solutions the way you say you know.